# the table contains a string that is too long for excel to display. if you edit the long value some data might be lost

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepointdocumentlibrary, excel-web-query

I have a sharepoint document library. On exporting to excel i get the message "the table contains a string that is too long for excel to display. if you edit the long value some data might be lost". Why is this message being displayed, and how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You've posted the same question on sharepoint.stackexchange.com also?? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/147974/41491

Comment: Please don't post the same question on more than one site.

Comment: sorry, would keep that in mind next time